# Saving an object to table that has relationship with another table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, data-persistence

I have 2 tables.

```
Student (id,name,class_id)<br>
class(id,name)
```

`student` relates to `class` table through `class_id`

after using hibernate and generate into object, I'll have 2 objects

```
Student { int id; String name; Class class }
Class {int id; String name; Set<Student> student}
```

I want to save student information using hibernate (`session.save(student)`). However, I have to call class through `class_id`. Therefore, is there anyway to save the student without get the class object using hibernate?

This is just an example, I have work with a database that a table has many relationship with the others, and it's a pain for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
student.setClass(null);
session.save(student);
```

should help. Although I am not sure what ". However, I have to call class through class_id" means.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at unidirectional one-to-many relationship(based on class definitions given above) from class to student. You also need to understand cascades. Go through [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html), and [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) to learn about associations as you said you have similar scenarios.